# MKRouteStep: Where is the location?

Tags: ios, dictionary, routes, navigation, mapkit

I want to make a custom turn by turn interface. Therefore I need the location of every step to calculate the distance in realtime. But it seems like the iOS7 Directions API does not expose the location in the response.

```
MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:directionsRequest];
[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {


    MKRoute *firstRoute = response.routes[0];
    NSArray *steps = firstRoute.steps;
    for (MKRouteStep *step in steps) {
        NSLog(@"---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        NSLog(@"instruction %@", step.instructions);
        NSLog(@"notice %@", step.notice);
        NSLog(@"distance %f", step.distance);
        NSLog(@"---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code to find the location of every step:

```
step.polyline.coordinate
```

Furthermore, in the `response` parameter there are source and destination of the route.